# The gravitation field of a "Kerr-Newman electron"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

Let us imagine a universe with a single electron.

Person A observes the electron (from outside this universe, assume it's possible) and it's gravitational field in a certain frame.
Furthermore it is a "spin up" electron.

Person B does the same thing, but his coordinate system is rotated w.r.t A's. His z-axis is A's y-axis. He observes the electron with spin up.

So now we have two observers who observe the axis's of spin in perpendicular directions to each other. Observations that are perfectly consistent in  quantum theory. But they imply the gravitation and all the effects of rotation, i.e., frame dragging look very different to either observer, since they are about perpendicular axis.

Has anyone ever examined this effect/paradox?

Comment: There can be no people in a single electron universe.

Comment: Can you write down this state that will measure +y and +z with certanty?

Comment: How does a single electron with spin 1/2 excite a graviton with spin 2? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The word observe (and the words measure and measurement) in quantum mechanics are totally misleading words (but they are both traditional and standard, so you have to live with it).

In particular when you measure or observe something in quantum mechanics you change it. And spin is a perfect example.

If you make an eigenstate of the operator $\hat \sigma_z$ and then make an eigenstate of the operator $\hat \sigma_z$ out of the same object and then make an eigenstate of the operator $\hat \sigma_x$ oit of the same object again you will find that the second eigenstate of $\hat \sigma_z$ is **always** the same as the first one.

So apparently measuring the operator $\hat \sigma_z$ puts the system into a state that always gives a particular eigenstate of $\hat \sigma_z$.

However if you make an eigenstate of the operator $\hat \sigma_z$ and then make an eigenstate of the operator $\hat \sigma_x$ out of the same object and then make an eigenstate of the operator $\hat \sigma_z$ out of the same object again you will find that the second eigenstate of $\hat \sigma_z$ is  **not** always the same as the first eigenstate of $\hat \sigma_z$.

So apparently, while the first interaction for $\hat \sigma_z$ put it into a definite state of $\hat \sigma_z$ but doing the interaction for $\hat \sigma_x$ puts into a **new** state, one that doesn't give a fixed singular result for a $\hat \sigma_z$ interaction.

So we call it an observation or a measurement, but it is provably an interaction that can change the state. It is not a passive revealer of a preexisting property. It is an active transformation into a new state.

So since the z and y components don't commute, observing it for one makes it change from what it was in the former.

Its like two blind roommates that disagree about where some furniture should be. Every time one roommate looks for it they move their hands in way that **makes** it become parallel or antiparallel to one axis, and then they locate it. And every time the other roommate looks for it they move their hands in way that **makes** it become parallel or antiparallel to a different axis., and then they locate it.

They might even start telling people about the unreality of quantum furniture. And tell people this is spooky. Which if they think they aren't changing things it is spooky. But clearly everyone knows that these so called measurements are changes of states and that is why when one roommate "measures" or "observes" the furniture they make it so the other roommate doesn't know which result they will get when they do it.

It isn't spooky. It isn't deep. Its just poor choice or terminology coupled with people wanting to act like things are more mysterious than they are.

Long story short. There is no such thing as being spin up in two different directions. When you force it to **become** spin up in one direction it will **now not** be in a definite spin up/down for any other direction.